# How to find a polynomial relation of 1 variable from 4 simultaneous equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have $4$ simultaneous equations derived from Saha equation to solve for plasma species evolution as
temperature changes, $4$ variables $x,y,z,w$ represent number density of electron, neutral atom, ion1+，ion2+,  $a,b,c$ represent some known constants.

$\frac{xz}{y}-a=0$

$\frac{xw}{z}-b=0$

$x+y+z+w-c=0$

$x-z-2w=0$

Rather than simultaneously solving $4$ equations, there is a polynomial equation to solve variable $x$ as

$x^3+2ax^2+(3ab-ac)x-2abc=0$

The rest $3$ variable is easily calculated once $x$ is known, and the outcome is indeed correct .

The problem is that I can't figure out how it is formulated, limiting me from extending one more equation and one more variable to calculate ion3+. For some reason, writer of this equation can't be consulted.

I have tried elimination but it didn't really go anywhere.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone willing to help（＞﹏＜）

Comment: Eliminate $z$ between $(4)$ and $(2)$ to get $w$ in terms of $x$. Then get $z$ from $(4)$, $y$ from $(3)$ and substitute in $(1)$ to get an equation in $x$ alone.

Comment: @dxiv You are very right! Sorry to bother you guys with such silly question.

Comment: @dxiv One more thing if not too inconvenient: I tried to form a matrix multiplication for the 4 equations, like A*X=B. But that seems only applys for equations with constant coefficients. Is matrix form impossible for equations where unknown variables multiply/divide with each other?

Comment: The matrix form is normally used for *linear* equations with constant coefficients. You *can* write non-linear equations and/or with non-constant coefficients in matrix form, but then you don't have a whole theory behind it to relate the roots to the matrices, like there is for linear systems.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your time!